# Dryer vent: Wall vs window

Tags: hvac, basement, windows, dryer, vent

The question: If you have a choice, is it better to vent an electric clothes dryer located in a cement block basement through a window or through the wall of the house? Is there a 'best practice' to follow here?

I'm doing some renovations on my 1942 Cape Cod. Previous owners, at one time or another, vented the electric dryer in the basement through an adjacent window right above the dryer and also through the wall of the house above the window. I know this because old vents exist in both places. I'll be replacing the horrible old wood window above the washer and dryer with glass block. I can easily incorporate a block with a built-in dryer vent when I do. I will also be siding the house, so that old vent will go away. I would think that, given a choice, the window is the way to go rather than piercing through new siding.

But if you are a pro or just someone with DIYer experience here I'd be interested in your take. I just want to this once by doing it right.

Pete

Comment: As a non pro, the best practice is the shortest straightest distance from the dryer to the outside.  The second best is the easiest shortest distance.  The vent should be cleaned every so often to remove dryer lint.

Comment: Be sure to add a screen on the outside.

Comment: To piggy-back on @crip659, whenever a dryer vent is going up, an in-line vent lint trap is recommended for the vent itself. Its also never recommended to use the slinky-like expandable hose for the vent since these are highly flammable, whereas galvanized steel vent piping is not.

Comment: @JW0914 I'm assuming you're talking plastic spiral ducting, not metal spiral ducting.

Comment: @Huesmann the semi-rigid one is fine the plastic foil one is flammable

Answer (score 1):

To consider:

- If water leaks into the wall where the vent comes out of the siding, that's not great.  If it leaks where you installed it in glass block in the foundation, it's probably not a big deal.
- If you mortar the vent into the glass block and have to replace it later, it will be a pain.
- If the steam from the dryer is ejected below the bottom of the siding, it may get behind the siding if it's something loose like vinyl or aluminum.  It won't be much but it may start to grow mildew, mold, or algae.

I would install it in the window and make sure the steam is thrown well away from the wall and downward so that it has more time to disperse before rising again.  Maybe a foot of vent pipe with a 45 degree elbow down and a removable screen at the end to keep critters out but allowing the thing to be cleaned.  Install it in a way that will let it be replaced relatively easily if it rusts or someone breaks it.

Comment: Why the downvote?